# Como utilizar o FindItem do QTreeWidget em PyQt ?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Tenho uma árvore `QTreeWidget` com vários itens previamente incluídos. Necessito procurar se uma uma string `x` tem o mesmo valor de texto do meu `QTreeWidgetItem`, ou seja necessito verificar todos os itens da minha árvore. Alguém sabe como posso utilizar esse método?

Ou como posso fazer com que meu `QTreeWidget` possa virar uma lista ?

Answer (score 1):

Tente o `findItems`, método do `QTreeWidget`:

```
tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
#...
items = tree.findItems("Teste", QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive, 0)
```

Isso produz uma lista com todos o items (`QTreeWidgetItem`) cujo texto bate com o parâmetro de pesquisa. Existem mais opções de pesquisa, dê uma olhada na [documentação](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#findItems) do método, principalmente nos valores de [`MatchFlag`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum).

Comment: Muito obrigado C. E. Gesser. Eu tinha utilizado o findItems porém não sabia que MatchFlag usar. Irei dar uma lida na documentação do método que eu estou lendo bastante e nos valores de MatchFlag também. Novamente Muito Obrigado ! :D